# angular 7 Services http with params "undefined"

Tags: angular

I've created an angular service, imported it and provide it in app.module.ts.

And I've created a Profile component that hold the data come from the service and imported RouterModule, Routes with const pages: Routes paths and it's okay
the problem that I get:

> VM16951:1 GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/undefined 404

Here is the code

PagerouteService.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PagerouteService {
  user: any;
  userid: any;
  result: any;
  constructor (public router: Router, public route: ActivatedRoute, public http: HttpClient) {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params:Params) => {this.user = params;});
    this.userid = this.user['id'];
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + this.userid).subscribe(data => {
      this.result = data;
    })
   }

}
```

ProfileComponent.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PagerouteService } from '../../services/pageroute.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  return:any;

  constructor(public pageRoute:PagerouteService) {
    this.return = this.pageRoute.result;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

profile.component.html

```html
<p>
  profile works!
</p>
<ul *ngIf="return">
  <li>{{return.id}}</li>
  <li>{{return.name}}</li>
  <li>{{return.username}}</li>
</ul>
```

Paths

```js
const pages:Routes = [
  {path: '*', component: AppComponent},
  {path: 'murtada', component: MurtadaComponent},
  {path: 'config', component: ConfigComponent},
  {path: 'userinfo', component: UserinfoComponent},
  {path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileComponent},
]
```

Comment: Please show your route definitions.

Comment: const pages:Routes = [
  {path:'*', component:AppComponent},
  {path:'murtada', component:MurtadaComponent},
  {path:'config', component:ConfigComponent},
  {path:'userinfo', component:UserinfoComponent},
  {path:'profile/:id', component:ProfileComponent},
]

Comment: Thank you - for readability, please edit your original answer and add it there.

Comment: sorry for bad codes in comment, done

Comment: Please consider [reviewing route params](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html), using a [resolver](https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/) to find your user or at the least [return the Observable from your service](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-creating-and-subscribing-to-observables-in-angular-426dbf0b04a3) and subscribe to it from the component that uses it. I realize you are new but there are significant issues with your code that you can solve by reading and understanding the documentation. Good luck!